# Wi-Fi from Arduino to computer serial COM

Tags: wifi, analogwrite

I am somewhat new to the Arduino world and so far having fun. I am making a gardening watering system for my first project. I am at the final stages of completion and want to add a Wi-Fi module on the Arduino to send to my computer and display via serial COM the soil moisture and other relevant measurements I have going.

Now my question is, is it possible the simple analog information from my Arduino to my computer's serial COM with the Wi-Fi module ?

Comment: I fail to see where the COM port fits into the equation.

Comment: Well like I said I am still very new, so when I usually display the analog information I can usually find it under the serial COM because thats where I printed it. Is there a simpler way I can view the information on my computer?

Comment: Well, with a WiFi module you are connected to your local network wirelessly. Your computer is already connected to that network, so you just communicate through the network. Programming that sort of thing is considerably more complex though.

Comment: But is it possible to have my Serial Monitor on my computer display the information from the arduino via wifi?

Comment: No. WiFi isn't serial. The closest you could get is through Telnet.

Comment: You can of course put a serial wifi-module at both the Arduino and the PC end and get exactly what you have asked for, but adding extra wifi hardware at the PC end just to get the data appearing on a serial port rather than a network socket seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Bluetooth, as Bluetooth communication is
mostly done by using **COM** Ports.

You can use **HC05**/**HC06** **Bluetooth** Modules with Arduino.
You can easily pair your PC with these Bluetooth Modules.

Now, you write an application in any programming language to get &
send data to your Arduino via Bluetooth COM ports.

Comment: ok Thank you, What is the difference between the HC05 and 06? Is one better than the other?

Comment: They are approximately the same. Either one will work. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ESP8266 with ESP-LINK firmware.

There is nothing to it.Check out [github.com/jeelabs/esp-link](http://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link) for documentation, examples and such.

Connect ESP8266 to Arduino URXD: 
connect to TX of microcontroller UTXD: 
connect to RX of microcontroller GPIO0: 
connect to RESET of microcontroller GPIO2:

optionally connect green LED to 3.3V (indicates wifi status) And that about it. Everything else is done over WiFi

Comment: How? Can you provide more details, circuit schematic, some code, an explanation?

Comment: There is nothing to it.Check out https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link for documentation, examples and such. Connect ESP8266 to Arduino URXD: connect to TX of microcontroller

UTXD: connect to RX of microcontroller

GPIO0: connect to RESET of microcontroller

GPIO2: optionally connect green LED to 3.3V (indicates wifi status) And that about it. Everything else is done over WiFi

Comment: Could you edit and update your answer, and put the extra details in there, rather than in comments? It just keeps the site tidier, as well as making your answer more succinct, and means people don't have to look through comments to get the complete picture. Thx.

Comment: As @Greenonline has indicated, please update your answer to better reflect and format what you've said in your comments.